# create toolbar in .chm file

Tags: chm

I have created a .chm file from multiple html files. Now I want to show my own toolbar on the top of .chm file. 
I have installed "htmlhelp.exe" to create .chm from html files.

Can we create our own toolbar ?

Comment: You could create a "toolbar" in the HTML with very limited functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not supported. CHMs are not an especially powerful tool, unfortunately. Help 2.x is no help either, as Microsoft's decided not to let anyone except themselves have the viewer tool. (There are third party ones but they're not great.) Not that it would add the functionality you're looking for...just venting a bit I suppose.